# Sort items array by price in JS ignore elements with same price

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to order a list of products with a Javascript and the script works well, but if two products have the same price the script just ignore one of them.

```
function myFunction() {var items = document.querySelectorAll('.vc_visible-item');
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('vc_pageable-slide-wrapper');
var parent = y[0];
var SortElements = new Object();
items.forEach(function(item, indx){
  var itemValue = parseFloat(item.querySelector('.price-product').textContent.replace('€', '').replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  SortElements[itemValue] = {'element': item, 'index': indx} ;
});
var keys = Object.keys(SortElements);
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  a = parseInt(a);
  b = parseInt(b);

  if (a <= b) return 1;
  if (a >= b) return -1;
 
}
keys.sort(compareNumeric);
keys.map(function(key, indx){
  parent.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', SortElements[key]['element']);
});
}
```

Anyone have any advice on how can i fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Without looking deeply, I would suggest that your cases in `compareNumeric` are wrong.  `if (a < b) return 1; if (a > b) return -1; /* else */ return 0`.

Comment: why not `return b-a`?

Comment: Already tryed both solutions and they didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue isn't with the "sort" its that you are overwriting the key in the SortElements object

```
SortElements[itemValue] = {'element': item, 'index': indx}
```

if the next item has the same price then you will overwrite SortElements[that price] with the new {element, index};

I would instead of inserting into an object.. insert into an array

```
function myFunction() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.vc_visible-item');
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('vc_pageable-slide-wrapper');
  var parent = y[0];
  var SortElements = [];
  items.forEach(function(item, indx){
    var itemValue = parseFloat(item.querySelector('.price-product').textContent.replace('€', '').replace(/\s+/g, ''));
    SortElements.push({'element': item, 'price':itemValue, 'index': indx});
  });
  function compareNumeric(a, b) {
    numA = a.price;
    numB = b.price;

    if (numA < numB) return 1;
    if (numA > numB) return -1;
    return 0;
  }
  SortElements.sort(compareNumeric);
  SortElements.forEach(function(item){
    parent.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', item.element);
  });
}
```

Comment: It don't work for me :( it seems tht SortElements.push block the execution of the script

Comment: After inserting the brackets in the SortElements.push({'element': item, 'price':itemValue, 'index': indx});
  }); work perfectly thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `items.forEach` loop, you are creating members in the `SortElements` object using the item's value as the name for each property. If the loop finds that a member with that name already exists, it is replacing the current value for that property with the new one that it encounters.
You could put a conditional around that line to check for the presence of that property.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you please help me with the code pls?